# Replace numbers in matrix with string

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix containing integers and a data frame with several columns.

Matrix:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    4    6   1    NA   NA
[2,]    2    3   NA   NA   NA   NA
[3,]    3    4    5    6    2    1
[4,]    6    6    2    3    3   NA
[5,]    1    2    1    4    5    6
[6,]    4   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

Data frame:

```
   V1   V2           V3             
1 "5P"  "Fox"       "28639"
2 "5P"  "Horse"     "33844"
3 "5P"  "Cat"       "Bes86"    
4 "5P"  "Seal"      "Bes259"   
5 "5P"  "Snake"     "Bes260"   
6 "5P"  "Platypus"  "NSA8631"
```

The actual data frame is much larger than this (10000+ rows).

What I want is to replace the numbers in the matrix with the corresponding row of V2 in my data frame. So that all "1" entries end up as "Fox", "2" as "Horse" and so on.

```
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]
[1,]       Fox      Seal  Platypus       Fox        NA        NA
[2,]     Horse       Cat        NA        NA        NA        NA
[3,]       Cat      Seal     Snake  Platypus     Horse       Fox
[4,]  Platypus  Platypus     Horse       Cat       Cat        NA
[5,]       Fox     Horse       Fox      Seal     Snake  Platypus
[6,]      Seal        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
```

Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: Be aware you will need a new matrix - matricies in R must be single-typed (unlike data frames).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This seems to do the trick:

```
#you convert the matrix to vector
#use it to index df2$V2
#and then reconstruct the matrix
matrix(df2$V2[as.vector(mat)], ncol=6)

#Or actually even better as @PierreLafortune messaged me
#you don't even need as.vector as this occurs automatically
matrix(df2$V2[mat], ncol=ncol(mat)) #result is the same
```

Data:

```
mat <- as.matrix(read.table(header=T,text='    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    4    6   1    NA   NA
[2,]    2    3   NA   NA   NA   NA
[3,]    3    4    5    6    2    1
[4,]    6    6    2    3    3   NA
[5,]    1    2    1    4    5    6
[6,]    4   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA'))

df2 <- read.table(text='V1   V2           V3             
1 "5P"  "Fox"       "28639"
2 "5P"  "Horse"     "33844"
3 "5P"  "Cat"       "Bes86"    
4 "5P"  "Seal"      "Bes259"   
5 "5P"  "Snake"     "Bes260"   
6 "5P"  "Platypus"  "NSA8631"   ')
```

Output:

```
    [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]    [,6]      
[1,] "Fox"      "Seal"     "Platypus" "Fox"      NA      NA        
[2,] "Horse"    "Cat"      NA         NA         NA      NA        
[3,] "Cat"      "Seal"     "Snake"    "Platypus" "Horse" "Fox"     
[4,] "Platypus" "Platypus" "Horse"    "Cat"      "Cat"   NA        
[5,] "Fox"      "Horse"    "Fox"      "Seal"     "Snake" "Platypus"
[6,] "Seal"     NA         NA         NA         NA      NA
```

Comment: @TARehman It seems to be character to be honest: `> typeof(matrix(df2$V2[mat], ncol=6))
[1] "character"`

Comment: Thanks @akrun :). If I said this for every answer of yours I felt this way, I wouln't have any time left to post answers :P

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `lookup` from `qdapTools`:

```
library(qdapTools)

matrix(lookup(c(mat), data.frame(1:nrow(df2),df2$V2)), ncol=ncol(mat))
#     [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]    [,6]      
#[1,] "Fox"      "Seal"     "Platypus" "Fox"      NA      NA        
#[2,] "Horse"    "Cat"      NA         NA         NA      NA        
#[3,] "Cat"      "Seal"     "Snake"    "Platypus" "Horse" "Fox"     
#[4,] "Platypus" "Platypus" "Horse"    "Cat"      "Cat"   NA        
#[5,] "Fox"      "Horse"    "Fox"      "Seal"     "Snake" "Platypus"
#[6,] "Seal"     NA         NA         NA         NA      NA
```